# CSS, Javascript, and Html NavBar not working

Tags: javascript, html, css

My nav bar isn't working. I don't know why. The javascript functions are doing opposite of what they are supposed to do. Also the open button isn't being seen. The x button does work. When I do close the navBar the open button isn't there. I have to refresh my screen for the box to appear again.

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>IKC Website</title>
</head>
<body>

    <span class="openNav" onclick="close()">&#9776; open</span>

    <div id ="sideNav" class="sideNav">
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closeButton" onclick="open()">&times;</a>
        <a href="about.html">About<a>
        <a href="members.html">Members<a>
        <a href="services.html">Services<a>
        <a href="contactUs.html">Contact Us<a>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
}

.openNav {
    font-size: 30px;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: relative;
    top: 100px;
    left: 100px;
    margin: 10px;
    z-index: 0;
    color: black;
}

.sideNav {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    width: 55vh;
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    z-index: 1;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    transition: 0.5s;
}

.sideNav a {
    color: #818181;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 40px;
    padding: 10px;
    transition: 0.3s;
    display: block;
}

.sideNav .closeButton {
    color: #818181;
    width: 100px;
    margin-left: 45vh;
    position: relative;
    left: 1vh;
    bottom: 17vh;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}

.sideNav a:hover{
    color: white;
}

@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
    .sideNav {
        padding-top: 50px;
    }
    .sideNav a {
        font-size: 18px;
    }
}
```

Javascript

```
function open() {
    document.getElementById("sideNav").style.width = "250px";
}

function close() {
    document.getElementById("sideNav").style.width = "0px";
}
```

Comment: The close button is currently calling `open()` and the open button is calling `close()`. This might be the reverse of what you want.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

try my code below:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <!-- <script src="script.js"></script>
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet"> -->
  <title>IKC Website</title>
</head>

<body>
  <style>
    body {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    }

    .openNav {
      font-size: 30px;
      cursor: pointer;
      position: relative;
      top: 100px;
      left: 100px;
      margin: 10px;
      z-index: 0;
      color: black;
    }

    .sideNav {
      position: fixed;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
      width: 55vh;
      height: 100vh;
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
      z-index: 1;
      overflow-x: hidden;
      transition: 0.5s;
    }

    .sideNav a {
      color: #818181;
      text-decoration: none;
      font-size: 40px;
      padding: 10px;
      transition: 0.3s;
      display: block;
    }

    .sideNav .closeButton {
      color: #818181;
      width: 100px;
      margin-left: 45vh;
      position: relative;
      left: 1vh;
      bottom: 17vh;
      margin-bottom: 0;
    }

    .sideNav a:hover {
      color: white;
    }

    @media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
      .sideNav {
        padding-top: 50px;
      }

      .sideNav a {
        font-size: 18px;
      }
    }
  </style>

  <span class="openNav" onclick="openFn()">&#9776; open</span>

  <div id="sideNav" class="sideNav">
    <a class="closeButton" onclick="closeFn()">&times;</a>
    <a href="about.html">About</a>
    <a href="members.html">Members</a>
    <a href="services.html">Services</a>
    <a href="contactUs.html">Contact Us</a>
  </div>
  <script>
    function openFn() {
      document.getElementById("sideNav").style.width = "55vh";
    }

    function closeFn() {
      document.getElementById("sideNav").style.width = "0px";
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Is there a reason the function names were changed?

Comment: I test the code in my chrome, I found there is already have the native function close and open. then the function you defined will not work. so make it safe, I change the func name

Comment: It's generally a good idea to explain things like that in the answer, as well as explaining why the answer solves the problem, things like that are very useful to people improving rather than just getting a quick fix

Answer (score -1):

Your "On" button is a child of the navigation bar, and of course disappears when you close the navigation bar.Causes the entry to open the navigation bar to disappear.

You should:

```js
    <span class="openNav" onclick="close()">&#9776; open</span>

    <div id ="sideNav" class="sideNav">
        <a href="about.html">About<a>
        <a href="members.html">Members<a>
        <a href="services.html">Services<a>
        <a href="contactUs.html">Contact Us<a>
    </div>

    <span class="closeButton" onclick="open()">&times;</span>
```

or use "toggle" on "openNav" to dynamically bind the class name to open or close it